# Mysql joins with complicated subquery

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have two select statements and I want to join them by their common column:

**First query:**

> select self_code as 'DSLAM_code', count(self_code) as 'Registered' from obj_port group by self_code;

**outputs:**

```
+------------+------------+
| DSLAM_code | Registered |
+------------+------------+
| 10000      |        317 |
| 10001      |        344 |
| 10002      |         93 |
+------------+------------+
```

**Second query:**

> select substring_index(dslamportid,":",1) as DSLAM_code,
>   count(substring_index(dslamportid,":",1)) as Active from radacct where
>   dslamportid like '%:%' group by substring_index(dslamportid,":",1);

**outputs:**

```
+------------+--------+
| DSLAM_code | Active |
+------------+--------+
| 10000      |    265 |
| 10001      |    299 |
| 10002      |     83 |
+------------+--------+
```

I am trying unsuccessfully  to **join the two output tables** with the following query:

> select A.self_code as 'DSLAM_code', A.count(self_code) as 'Registered'
>   from obj_port A group by F.self_code  left join  (select
>   substring_index(dslamportid,":",1) as dslam,
>   count(substring_index(dslamportid,":",1)) as count from radacct where
>   dslamportid like '%:%' group by substring_index(dslamportid,":",1))  B
>   on A.self_code = B.dslam;

I get get syntax errors :

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'left join  (select
>   substring_index(dslamportid,":",1) as dslam, count(substring_' at line
>   2

Thanks in advance dear community!

Comment: You cannot have a group by statement before a join statement.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a way to do it:

> select a.DSLAM_code , a.Registered, b.active from ( select self_code
>   as 'DSLAM_code', count(self_code) as 'Registered' from obj_port group
>   by self_code )  a  left  join ( select
>   substring_index(dslamportid,":",1) as DSLAM_code,
>   count(substring_index(dslamportid,":",1)) as Active from radacct where
>   dslamportid like '%:%' group by substring_index(dslamportid,":",1) ) b
>   on  a.dslam_code = b.dslam_code;